# Need a JPA query which sorts Posts, posted on last 4hours

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, jpql

@Repository
public interface PostRepository extends JpaRepository {

```
Page<Post> findAllByCategory(Pageable pageable, Category category);


LocalDate dateBefore4Hours = LocalDate.now().minus(4, ChronoUnit.HOURS); //tried but couldnt figured it out


@Query("SELECT a FROM Post a WHERE a.createdDate  ") //none of sql keywords i've tried here didnt wor
Page<Post> findAllWithCreationDateTimeInLastFourHours();
```

}

Comment: Btw, im newbie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to compare time you may use `LocalDateTime`, because `LocalDate` don't have the time component. So to get the `LocalDateTime` of 4 hours ago you can do this:

```java
LocalDateTime currentTimeMinus4Hours = LocalDateTime.now().minusHours(4L);
```

Then you can just use that in your query and sort the column, just like so:

```java
@Query("SELECT a FROM Post a WHERE a.createdDate > :currentTimeMinus4Hours ORDER BY a.createdDate")
Page<Post> findRecentPosts(LocalDateTime currentTimeMinus4Hours);
```

Comment: Ty so much, i think it worked. So i assume when i define a method, i can use it with jpql using " :colon: "  right?

Comment: Yes, you can referente the method arguments with ":argument" in the JPQL query. Remember to mark this answer as correct if it solved the issue. Thanks!